# Spectral Python Display not staying up

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm experimenting with the spectral python library, and whenever I try to re-create the first example here:  http://www.spectralpython.net/graphics.html 
the image window appears and immediately disappears.  I'm scripting this in Pycharm, what am I doing wrong?

My code is identical to the code in the example, without the line numbers of course

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had bigger problems, I wasn't using the WX backend for matplotlib, meaning any attempt to display a window was all for naught.  I've since moved to Anaconda, and have run into all new errors!  But at least not this one :D